# Reaching element from ID in jQuery listener

Tags: jquery, listener, selector

I have some HTML like this:

```
<select id="myselect">
  <option>...</option>
  <option>...</option>
  <option>...</option>
</select>

<div class="myclass" id="mydiv">[...]</div>
```

and, im my js

```
$("#myselect").addEvents({
  ..., 
  change: function(){
    $("#mydiv").addClass("anotherclass");
  }
  ...
});
```

Well, my script can't fine `$("#id")`, neither in the js console of Chrome Developers Tools. What's going on? Is that possible that in the listener, where the `this` object is the event raiser, the `$("")` selector doesn't work properly?

Thank you

EDIT: just a typo in the question, I forgot the `#` in the first selector. problem is still on.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is `addEvents`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was watching just a little part o the code; now I red it and it seems to be MooTools, and not jQuery; I didn't noticed before. So, I think that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have miss `#` into the jquery selector
Try this:

```
$("#myselect").addEvents({
  ..., 
  change: function(){
    $("#mydiv").addClass("anotherclass");
  }
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it must be `$("#myselect")` instead of `$("myselect")`

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to use document ready ? because jQuery can't find elements if you try to select them before the DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myselect").addEvents({ ....

  ... })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`addEvents()` is not a jQuery method (I believe it is MooTools), if you want to bind event handlers using the same syntax as above, use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#example-6):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myselect').on({
        change: function() {
            $('#mydiv').addClass('anotherClass');
        }
    });
});
```